# Segmentation fault in linux 64 bit assembly language (Beginner)

Tags: linux

Getting a segmentation fault and output is not as desired in linux 64 bit assembly language. Beginner. Any help would be appreciated. Seeking help first here before I speak to TA/professor. Here is the link to the site for reference:
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~langley/CIS4385-2014-1/Assign2-new.html

Here is my code thus far:

```
.text                           # Start of code segment

.global _start              # Declaring for linker (ld)

_start:
                            # String to stdout

      movl    $len,%edx           # Argument: message length
      movl    $msg,%ecx           # Argument: pointer to message to write
      movl    $1,%ebx             # Argument: file handle (stdout)
      movl    $4,%eax             # System call number (sys_write)
      syscall                     # Invokes system calls in Linux

      movl    $0,%ebx             # Argument: exit code
      movl    $1,%eax             # System call number (sys_exit)
      syscall                     # Invokes system calls in Linux

.data                           # Start of data segment

msg:
    .ascii    "Hello World (64 bit version) --- this is MY NAME!\n"
    .ascii    "\n"
    .ascii    "CIS 4385 Spring 2014\n"
    len = . - msg                 # length of string
```

Answer (score 3):

You confused x86 assembly with x86_64 assembly.

1. Register names are different.  `%edx` vs `%rdx`, `%ebx` vs `%rdi`, ... You need to read about x86_64 conventions.  It isn't a simple replacement from `%e..` to `%r..` !
   Plus, if you just write `mov $1,%rax`, then GNU `as(1)` will choose an appropriate variant of `mov` for you (`movq` in this case)
2. Syscall numbers are different.  `SYS_write` is `1`, for example.  See `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` for the full list.

FYI, this is how to use GDB:

```
$ gdb -tui ./your.exe -ex 'break _start' -ex run
(gdb) layout next
(gdb) (hit Enter, Enter... until you get a desired view)
(gdb) nexti # or stepi, if you want to go into a function call
(gdb) (hit Enter, Enter, ...)
```